# Number of dropdowns based on selection of first dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Programming in Bootstrap and PHP I am trying to create a dynamic form which has the following.

User uses a dropdown to select number from 1 to 10.
The page then displays x number of dropdowns.

Each dropdown is the same and displays a list of userID from a MySQL table tblUsers

Once the user makes a selection from each dropdown, it then shows a second dropdown immediately underneath showing a list of videos from a second MySQL table tblVideos. Meaning that the second dropdown is based on the results from the first.

Once all dropdowns have been selected. Submit is pressed and the results are sent as an array to the table tblVideoStored

Any ideas how the PHP and MySQL would be in a simple form..

Comment: What have you tried so far? And are the videos in tblVideos linked to the tblUsers table via userID?

Comment: Have both accepted and answered comments.

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you plan to achieve, you may want to look into combining php with ajax (Javascipt). Below are some examples that should set you on the right path

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-ajax-to-populate-dropdown-menu/4350/2

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/using-jquery-ajax-populate-selection-list/